# how to get an elasticsearch aggregation by multiple fields concat

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregate, concatenation

i want to get an ES aggregation by two or more fields, but not to aggregate one by one, but to concat() these fields as a new one, and aggregate by these new one filed, so how to do it ? thanks

Comment: please describe what have you tried so far.

Answer (score 5):

Although it's an old post, might be useful to someone. Something like this could work:

```
GET index/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query":{ 
    "match_all": {}
  },
  "aggs": {
    "unique_count": {
      "cardinality": {
        "script": {
          "lang": "painless",
          "source": "doc['field1'].value + '#' + doc['field2'].value"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I've tried this and didn't work, I had to use "terms" instead of "cardinality". But doing this, I get the values of the fields between square brackets, e.g. `[value1]#[value2]`

Comment: Write it like this to eliminate the list representation: "source": "doc['field1'].value[0] + '#' + doc['field2'].value[0]"